# Term to describe events sacrificing the system performance?

Tags: word-choice, terminology

> Cache misses are one of the most well-known **performance-losing** events.

To provide some background, *cache misses* are one of the main causes of computer system slowdowns, obstructing computers from consuming cycles in useful computation work. What I mean by **performance-losing** is that cache misses are the kinds of events that slow down the computer, but I think the **losing** one is computers, not events. I considered terms like **performance-stealing** or **performance-weakening**, but I have no idea whether these terms are commonly used or seem natural. Could anyone recommend the term to describe this?

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the fact that you can construct several different sentences with the same meaning, in line with your question I can suggest **performance degradation**.

> Cache misses are one of the most well-known causes for **performance degradation** in computer systems.

Answer (score 0):

*Performance-losing* certainly doesn't sound natural. How about *performance-diminishing*? Or better still, restructure the sentence into something like:

> Cache misses are well-known for **diminishing/reducing/lowering/decreasing/worsening** performance in computer systems.